# gtags for cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gnu, development, ctags

This might be a silly question, and hopefully it's not off-topic, but I can't figure out where else to ask.

Is gtags available for cygwin? I'm using ctags but it'd be nice to have all the extra functionality of gtags on Windows.

I didn't see it in the list on [cygwin ports](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/cygwinports/portslist.txt) or in the [kernel.org packages](http://mirrors.kernel.org). Could it be somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not in the cygwin ports, it's not. You should consider building it from source.

EDIT

Googling for gnu globals cygwin I found build instructions:

http://sophie.zarb.org/distrib/PLD/ac/ppc/rpms/global/files/11

This source also lists the necessary dependencies.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you. I have neither given critique, nor asked for a clarification from OP. He asks if a package is available for Cygwin, the answer is _"it's not"_. Since this is the only correct answer, I fail to see how it "does not provide an answer".  Obviously like anyone else I am only speaking from my own knowledge, so if yours is better please do feel free to educate me and the OP. Furthermore I am providing a possible way to make the desired tool available - I again fail to see how this does "not provide an answer". Could you please clarify?

Comment: Answers are intended to be definitive--this is a wiki, not a bbs. If you are not confident in your response, leave it as a comment.

Comment: Based on Anthon's edit (thanks BTW) and your referral to "not confident" (I am) my mistake appears to be "... I doubt it". Sorry for the confusion, that's just my usual way of expression. Thanks for critique, I will keep that in mind. Answer edited to more definitive format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows binary port directly:
http://adoxa.altervista.org/global/

It can be also called from CYGWIN once is added in PATH env.